# Batch file to execute all files in a folder

Tags: batch-file, dos

I need a batch files the launches all files in a given folder (in this case it is c:\macros\day).

I've tried the following, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

```
for /f %i in ('C:\macros\Day /b') DO command %i
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This works from my command line:

```
for /F "usebackq" %%i in (`dir /b C:\macros\Day\`) DO %%i
```

as does this:

```
for %%i in (C:\macros\Day\*) do %%i
```

Comment: shouldn't this be `for /F "usebackq" %i in...`?

Answer (score 6):

You used the incorrect variant of `for`. simply do (pun intended) `for %%i in (c:\macros\Day\*) do %%i`

Edit:
If you need to run a `command` on all files: `for %%i in (c:\macros\Day\*)  do command %%i`

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

However that give me:

\macros\Day\*) was unexpected at this time.

Comment: It should be, `for %i in (c:\macros\Day\*) do COMMAND %i` (you need to specify the command that operates on %i)

Comment: if run from batch file, you need to replace %whatever with %%whatever (so %i becames %%i and so forth). You've given your example with single %, so I did as well..

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger yes you're right I will update the answer (reading question I was under the impression OP wants to fire something directly executable)

Answer (score 2):

You should use `dir /b` to list all files, so it becomes

```
for /f %i in ('dir /b c:\macros\Day') do command %i
```

Comment: With double % if you put it in a batch file

Answer (score 0):

Also, make sure that you make variables inside batch files %%i rather than %i otherwise you get an error in the form "i was unexpected at this time."

Answer (score 0):

[Running all files in directory via batch file with appended text on each line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15073139/running-all-files-in-directory-via-batch-file-with-appended-text-on-each-line)

An alternative is posted above - leave off the trailing "/Z /U" if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I could run all powershell files in same directory as the batch file

```
@ECHO OFF

SET PowerShellExe=%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe

for %%i in (*.ps1) do (

%PowerShellExe% -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command %cd%\%%i    

)
```